# General method for finding the splitting field of $x^a+c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

I was aked to find the splitting field of polynomial like $x^4+1, x^6+1, x^4-2$, etc. The roots of unity started appearing and I had an idea.

A polynomial $x^a+c$ (lets suppose $c\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a\in \mathbb{Z}$) is gonna have $a$ roots, right? These roots are always equally distributed in the complex plane (that is, the angle between two consecutive ones is gonna be $\pi/a$.

When $c=1$ the first root can be thought of being $e^{i\pi/a}$, because $(e^{i\pi/a})^a = e^{i\pi} = -1$ and then this root solves $x^a=-1$

When $c=-1$ the first root can be thought of being $e^{i2\pi/a}$, because $(e^{i2\pi/a})^a = e^{i2\pi} = 1$ and then this root solves $x^a=1$

In both cases, all the other roots are gonna be powers of the first root I described. In the cases where $c\neq \pm 1$, it is just a constant times $\pm 1$ and the same rules apply, but the firts root is gonna be just the first roof of unity times a constant.

So, when we wanna take the splitting field of any of these polynomails $x^a+c$ I described, we wanna find

$$\mathbb{Q}(r_1, r_2, \cdots r_a)$$

But since the $r_2,\cdots r_a$ roots are just powers of $r_1$, is it true that

$$\mathbb{Q}(r_1, r_2, \cdots r_a) = \mathbb{Q}(r_1)$$

?

Then,

$$[\mathbb{Q}(r_1, r_2, \cdots r_a):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(r_1):\mathbb{Q}]$$

?

This intuition came from this answer of another question I did: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439495/166180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  The problem is that for general $c$, the other roots are not powers of $r_1$.  Rather, the other roots have the form $r_1\omega^n$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/a}$.  So the splitting field can be described as $\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\omega)$, but not necessarily as $\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$.

For a very concrete example, consider $x^4-2$.  You can take the first root $r_1$ to be the positive real root $\sqrt[4]{2}$.  But $\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$ is then contained in $\mathbb{R}$, so cannot be the entire splitting field since not all the roots are real.  Instead the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(r_1,i)$, where $i=e^{2\pi i/4}$ is a primitive $4$th root of unity.

Comment: But what if I take the 'first' complex root?

Comment: If we take the first root to be a scale version of $e^{i\pi/2}$ then when we multiply it by itself we're gonna get all roots and also the real one

Comment: Ok, I get it. For the cases when $c\neq \pm 1$, when we multiply the root by a power of itself, we get larger or smaller modulus, but the correct angle. So in the cases where $c\neq \pm 1$, we're going to have always $\mathbb{Q}(r_1, e^{\pi/\mbox{something}})$? And in the cases $c=\pm 1$ we're gonna have $\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$?

Comment: Right.  Although, there are cases with $c\neq \pm 1$ where the root of unity $\omega$ may be in $\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$ by coincidence.  For instance, if you take $x^6+3$, then $r_1^3$ is a square root of $-3$ and $e^{2\pi i/6}=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\in\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$.

Comment: But in those cases I can just pick another root as the 'first' one, right?

Comment: No.  If $r$ is any root of $x^6+3$ at all, then $e^{2\pi i/6}\in\mathbb{Q}(r)$ so $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ is the splitting field.  More generally, if $x^a+c$ is irreducible, then $\mathbb{Q}(r_i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(r_j)$ for any two roots $r_i$ and $r_j$, so one is the splitting field iff any other is.